# Missing Reference or Directive for Only Caliburn.Micro Xamarin Example

Tags: reference, xamarin, caliburn.micro

I am attempting to compile the [HubBrowser project](https://github.com/nigel-sampson/xamarin-experiments) - which is an example Caliburn Micro Xamarin project (one of the very few there are).

Its a great example but the Android project is not compiling. I get the following errors:

```
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'CaliburnApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   HubBrowser\HubBrowser.Android\Application.cs    14  32  HubBrowser.Android
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'ActivityLifecycleCallbackHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  HubBrowser\HubBrowser.Android\Services\ApplicationNavigationService.cs  12  26  HubBrowser.Android
Error   9   The type or namespace name 'ActivityEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) HubBrowser\HubBrowser.Android\Services\ApplicationNavigationService.cs  24  55  HubBrowser.Android
Error   10  The type or namespace name 'ActivityEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) HubBrowser\HubBrowser.Android\Services\ApplicationNavigationService.cs  29  54  HubBrowser.Android
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

I have made sure my references point to `Caliburn.Micro` and `Caliburn.Micro.Platform` (net45 versions). Do I need `Caliburn.Micro.Portable.Core`? If so where is this dll? Installing C.M through NuGet always fails - these NuGet packages and PCL's are and ABSOLUTE nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pre-release 3.0 beta package.  In the Core PCL project, install Caliburn.Micro.Core 3.0.0-beta1, and in your Android project, install Caliburn.Micro 3.0.0-beta1 (which will also install Core as a dependency).

Be sure to check the "pre-release" checkbox in the Nuget dialog or else you won't see the beta releases.